# How to extract grouping variable with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to write out some messages within `group_by`+`mutate`.

Example with `nest`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)


find_mean <- function(data,cyl){
  message(paste0("mean of mpg is ",mean(data$mpg)," with cylinder ",cyl))
  mean(data$mpg)
}


mtcars %>%
  nest(-cyl) %>%
  mutate(v=pmap(list(data,cyl),find_mean))

mean of mpg is 19.7428571428571 with cylinder 6
mean of mpg is 26.6636363636364 with cylinder 4
mean of mpg is 15.1 with cylinder 8
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl data               v        
  <dbl> <list>             <list>   
1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]>  <dbl [1]>
2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]> <dbl [1]>
3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]> <dbl [1]>
```

How do I achieve the same thing with `group_by`? I know there is `group_keys` but I am not sure how to incorporate it into `mutate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cur_group`.

If you need the `message` try

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(message(paste0("mean of mpg is ", mean(mpg), 
    " with cylinder ", cur_group())))
mean of mpg is 26.6636363636364 with cylinder 4
mean of mpg is 19.7428571428571 with cylinder 6
mean of mpg is 15.1 with cylinder 8
# A tibble: 32 × 11
# Groups:   cyl [3]
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

or as a variable

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(message = paste0("mean of mpg is ", mean(mpg), 
    " with cylinder ", cur_group()), .groups="drop") %>% 
  select(-cyl)
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  message                                        
  <chr>                                          
1 mean of mpg is 26.6636363636364 with cylinder 4
2 mean of mpg is 19.7428571428571 with cylinder 6
3 mean of mpg is 15.1 with cylinder 8
```